# Debug JHipster Frontend with Visual Studio Code

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, visual-studio-code, jhipster, vscode-debugger

I have installed [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) extension to VS Code. How to bring up JHipster Angular application, which is using webpack in debug mode?

The JHipster Angular is under `<application>/src/main/webapp/app` and webpack configuration is under `<application>/webpack/webpack.dev.js`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps to bring up

1. Open folder or create project at your application **root** level, NOT `<your-app>/src/main/webapp` or `<your-app>/src/main/webapp/app`
2. Add chrome debugger configuration as below. Ensure port is 9000.
3. Start JHipster backend: `mvnw -P-webpack -Dmaven.test.skip=true`
4. Start JHipster frontend Angular: `npm start`
5. Set necessary break point in your Angular project
6. Start #1 debugger profile (F5 or play button)

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:9000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```